# Is NextJS 13 Route Handler Secure?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, next.js, https

In my NextJS 13 web app, I’m trying to implement an API using route handlers to perform actions such as signing up, logging in a user etc. When passing sensitive info such as the user’s password to the API endpoint, from a client component, is it secure and do I need to encrypt it?

My plan is to pass user info as json in the body of the request. What security considerations should I be aware of using NextJS route handlers?

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to web security, the easiest way to learn more about how-to would be to visit the OWASP best practice.

In this case, OWASP suggests handling passwords by multiple options, such as salting and peppering, with the example hashing algorithm provided in their doc.

The high-level idea would be as soon as the user clicks "submit" and sends their account credential, the password is hashed/encrypted and will be stored in the DB. It doesn't really matter whether you are using NextJS or any other frameworks.

Although depends on your client's need, they probably won't even care if you don't hash it. But that's up to you and your client to decide.

Read more here.

https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet.html#password-storage-concepts

Comment: Thank you. I should’ve stated in my question that I’m using Firebase Auth which typically would call sign up methods directly from the client. So I need the password in plain text to pass as an argument to the firebase  method, but need to get it from the client to the API endpoint. Is there any known convention for this sort of thing?

Comment: @Sylith To clarify -- the password should be hashed/encrypted in the back-end after receiving it from the front-end. So front-end will send the request with the password in plaintext. As long as the request is done via HTTPS it will be safe. As long as Firebase will do the hashing/encrypting of the password before storing into the DB, it will suffice.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if NextJS route handler uses HTTPS by default? I couldn't find anything specific in the docs. Perhaps it is just standard to use HTTPS these days?

Comment: thats really a whole different topic since it has nothing to do with what web framework you use, but different factor. Easiest way is to pay upfront to your web hosting provider to do the job for you (usually very easy and cheap) or DIY. Read more about it here https://support.google.com/domains/answer/7630973